# SASS + SMACSS properly encapsulating modules

Tags: html, css, sass, smacss

Here is my setup:

**File Relationships**

```
home.php <---styles---- _layout.scss
   |
imports
   |
   v
animation.html <---styles---- _animation.scss
```

**home.php** - the file used to outline the "layout" HTML for the homepage:

```
<div id="animation">
    <div class="site-container">

        <div class="animation-container">
            <?php include 'animation.html'; ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**_layout.scss** - the files used to style the non-imported contents of home.php:

```
#animation {
    //styles <div id="animation">
}

    .site-container {margin: 0 auto; max-width: 980px;}

        .animation-container {
            //styles <div class="animation-container">
        }
```

**animation.html** - contains the html for the "module" called "animation" imported above

```
<div class="animation-wrap">
    <div class="example-selector"></div>
    //more html for animation module
</div>
```

**_animation.scss** - styles the html in animation.html

**Question:**
How should I be encapsulating the selectors in _animation.scss?

**Possibilities**

1.) I could nest all selectors in _animation.scss like so:

```
.animation-wrap {

    .example-selector {

    }
    //all other selectors are nested here using SASS, thus they will not affect
    //elements outside of the animation-wrap
}
```

2.) I could namespace almost all selectors in _animation.scss by adding the prefix "animation-" (and in the corresponding html)

```
.animation-wrap {}

.animation-example-selector {}
```

3.) Could use child selectors to reduce cascading, but I doubt that's best and it has poor IE support

4.) Subclassing? But, I think that is more relevant to moving the module elsewhere, not encapsulating it to make sure it doesnt leak into other module/layout code

**Sorry for the long-winded question, it was awkward to put into words. Any additional advise or knowledge of best practice is greatly appreciated**

Comment: Unless your question is "how do I get this output", your question is off-topic.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121289/are-questions-about-naming-classes-relevant-on-stack-exchange and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90637/is-it-ok-to-ask-a-question-about-naming-conventions

Comment: Where are you using smacss?  I don't see any naming conventions even close to smacss in your code.

Comment: @cimmanon sorry for the bad question

Comment: @Lowkase

Maybe I should prefix _layout.scss selectors with '.l-'. Thanks for pointing that out. I am using SMACSS to separate code for the layout (_layout.scss) and modules (the example module given is _animation.scss).

SMACSS is, in large, not about naming conventions. While it does contain a few, the focus of SMACSS is modularizing code to make it scalable. Naming conventions are more in the domain of things like BEM.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the poor question. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150444/smacss-semantic-class-names-and-nested-elements) is a better worded question for a similar problem.

I decided to use SASS 3.3's brand new '&' flexibility to namespace the selectors in **_animation.scss** like so

```
.module-animation { 
        &-animation-wrap {

        }
}
```

This keeps the html clean, encapsulates the module, and doesn't clutter the css with long prefixes.